# Reading only HTML Content from a Web site page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using C#, and I'd like to scrape all the content on a site (but not the images, scripts, or files that may be attached to the page).  How do I do that with C# and ASP.NET?

Comment: Do you want to read HTML of the page at server side or what?

Comment: You need to provide more details, your question is not clear.

Comment: You want to extract the text only from webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can use the following code snippet from [HERE](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx) to do that:

```
StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
byte[]        buf = new byte[8192];

HttpWebRequest  request  = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.your-url.com");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

string tempString = null;
int    count      = 0;
do
{
    count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    if (count != 0)
    {
        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
        sb.Append(tempString);
    }
}
while (count > 0);

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the HTML at `Render` method of the `Page` as following.

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

            HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            base.Render(writer);
            string markupText = sb.ToString();
            // markupText will contain the HTML of the Page
            writer.Write(markupText);
        }
```